# Call a __init__ function from another function

Tags: python, recursion

I need some help form all of you, so i have something like this

```
class LoginFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        ...
        ...
        ...
   def _login_btn_clickked(self):

        ...
        ...
        result = messagebox.askyesno("Wrong username or password.", "Do you want to try again?")
        if result == True:
             self.__init__(self)
```

So if the user select the option to try again i need the whole program start again, and show the login box. But when i execute the program the process fail.

Comment: What do you mean by fail? What is the error?

Comment: Well actually is not failing. After the user click on Yes for try again. The programs does nothing just hung up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when i execute the program the process fail.

Actually it should. `__init__` method is normally called once an instance is created. You need to redesign this to either recreate an instance (first call `pack_forget` on that frame and then make new one and pack on that place), or do it using methods, like `show_loginbox` etc

Usually, loginboxes are made using `Toplevel` with `Entry` as fields and some buttons to post a result. If done so, on error you could simply erase login or/and passwords entry box and show an error
What I mean is:

[image: first]
[image: next]

reference implementation of above is [here](https://gist.github.com/thodnev/8cd74504a776933bcf110574c7bb7c76)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tkinter.Frame?

I should think that it wouldn't like being reconstructed through the use of 
    super().**init**()
While already being packed into a root window (I'm adsuming that is the setup you have).